# Pylint warning for "useless super delegation"

Tags: python, python-2.7, super, pylint

Pylint raises the warning: `Useless super delegation in method '__init__' (useless-super-delegation)` for the `SpecificError` class below.

```
class MyProjectExceptions(Exception):
    """The base class for all my project's exceptions."""
    def __init__(self, message, func):
        super(MyProjectExceptions, self).__init__(message)  # Normal exception handling
        self.func = func  # Error origin for logging

class SpecificError(MyProjectExceptions):
    """Raise when a specific error occurs."""
    def __init__(self, message, func):
        super(SpecificError, self).__init__(message, func)
```

What is the correct way to pass the parameters to the superclass here?

Comment: Why does `SpecificError` have its own `__init__`? You could just delete that method entirely and use the inherited implementation. (Unlike some other languages, `__init__` is inherited like any other method in Python.)

Comment: So would the best practice then be to omit the `__init__` entirely leaving only the docstring or replace it with `pass`?

Comment: Related: [Pylint issues useless-super-delegation instead of useless-constructor](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1567)

Answer (score 49):

If you call the `SpecificError` class it will look for an `__init__`. If it doesn't exist it will call the parent's `__init__`. There is no need to add an `__init__` here, since it's exactly the same like the parent class. It is basically code duplication.

You should do:

```
class SpecificError(MyProjectExceptions):
    """Raise when a specific error occurs."""
```

Comment: However by doing that I doubt that the class types will be correct under all scenarios. I wonder if isinstance and friends would work

Comment: But if there are parameters required by the constructor please mention them in the class docstring. Otherwise you have no idea what parameters are required.

Comment: The `pass` is not necessary either. Pylint will also complain about it with " W0107: Unnecessary pass statement (unnecessary-pass)"

Comment: what if the specific error has a default value for the message passed to init?

Comment: @TheFool - well then you should override `__init__` in `SpecificError` and you should no longer get the pylint warning because you _are_ doing something different to the base class's constructor.

Answer (score 18):

As [Mathieu mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017312/3357935), you don't need to override `__init__` in `SpecificError` since you are only calling `super()`.

```
class MyProjectExceptions(Exception):
    """The base class for all my project's exceptions."""
    def __init__(self, message, func):
        super(MyProjectExceptions, self).__init__(message)  # Normal exception handling
        self.func = func  # Error origin for logging

class SpecificError(MyProjectExceptions):
    """Raise when a specific error occurs."""
```

Pylint's developers explain `useless-super-delegation` in a bit more depth on the [Pylint changelog](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/1.7.html):

> `useless-super-delegation` [is] used whenever we can detect that an
> overridden method is useless, relying on `super()` delegation to do the
> same thing as another method from the MRO.
>
> For instance, in this example, the first two methods are useless,
> since they do the exact same thing as the methods from the base
> classes, while the next two methods are not, since they do some extra
> operations with the passed arguments.
>
> ```
> class Impl(Base):
>
>     def __init__(self, param1, param2):
>         super(Impl, self).__init__(param1, param2)
>
>     def useless(self, first, second):
>         return super(Impl, self).useless(first, second)
>
>     def not_useless(self, first, **kwargs):
>         debug = kwargs.pop('debug', False)
>         if debug:
>             ...
>         return super(Impl, self).not_useless(first, **kwargs)
>
>     def not_useless_1(self, first, *args):
>         return super(Impl, self).not_useless_1(first + some_value, *args)
> ```
>
> <sup>[What's New In Pylint 1.7](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/1.7.html)</sup>

The warning's creator further explains in a [commit message](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/commit/c48d948c06d31fa8bfa68badda04f081be7fcf4a):

> This is used whenever pylint can detect than an overridden method is
> useless, relying on `super()` delegation to implement the same thing as
> another method from [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro). In this case, it is enough to not implement
> the given method and let it be propagated to the another implementation
> from the MRO.

For the original issue report, see [*#839 - Pylint rule against people overriding a method just to call super*](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/839).

Comment: This then leads to `W0107: Unnecessary pass statement (unnecessary-pass)` ?